# Which one is faster / more stable: inverting matrix or solving three systems of linear equations with multiple right hand sides?

Tags: matrix, big-o, inversion, linear-equation

I have two equations I'm solving on each recursive round:

X = A - inv(B) * Y * inv(B), 
X = X + A' * inv(B) * A,

I solve the problem this way:

C = inv(B)*Y <=> BC = Y, solve C.
D = C*inv(B) <=> DB = C <=> B'D' = C', solve D'

E = inv(B)*A <=> BE = A, solve E.

All matrices change over time, so I have to do this (or inverting) again every recursion. N is usually about 1-10, possibly more, but usually something like that. B is positive definite so I can use cholesky on factorisation, and then solve equations of multiple right hand sides.

Is this much slower or faster than just inverting B and then doing matrix multiplications with that? One invertion vs solving three systems of linear equations (there's that another equation too) plus some transposing. I would think it's at least numerically more stable than inverting?

Thanks.

Comment: What is known, and what is unknown? Also, where's the Y dependency in your second equation? Right now it says A' * inv(B) * A ==' 0.
X, Y and A are vectors and B is a matrix?

Comment: Sorry, there's error in second equation, of course it should be 
X = Y + A'*inv(B)*A
 everything else is known but X and of course inv(B) (B is known). And the X, Y and A in second equation aren't same as in first... X, A, Y and B are all p*p matrices in both equations.

Comment: Ok, when solving for example BC = Y you divide that one into several systems of linear equations by solving Bc(i) = y(i), i=1..n.

Comment: Yes. I take cholesky decomposition of B, and use that to solve those equations using Lapacks subroutines. I'm just wondering which one is faster, solve so many linear equations, or just invert B.

Comment: I'll get back to you. I'm currently sick so don't have the energy right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's assume that all your matrixes are of order n x n. The cholesky factorization can then be done in O(n^3/6) operations (for large values of n).

Solving B*c(i) = y(i) or L*L'*c(i) = y(i) (Cholesky) is 2*O(n^2/2)  or O(n^2), but solving BC=Y is solving n of these equations (because Y is n x n), so at total we have O(n^3).

Solving D' is obviously analogous to this, so another O(n^3).

Transposing D' to D is rougly O(n^2), no calculations though, just swapping of data (apart from the diagonal elements which of course are the same).

Solving E in BE = A in the second formula is backwards substitution of cholesky factorization once more, so O(n^3)

A' * E is n^2 * (n mult and n-1 add) which is O(2*n^3 - n^2)

This sums up to: O(n^3/6) + 3*O(n^3) + O(n^2) + O(2*n^3 - n^2) ~ O(31*n^3/6) ~ O(5*n^3) (for large values of n)

Note that I haven't calculated the matrix additions/subtractions, but this isn't relevant because they will be the same if we decide to invert B. I have also skipped A to A' for the same reasons.

Ok, so how expensive is inverting a matrix? Well we wan to solve the matrix equation:

B * inv(B) = I, which is the same as solving B * x(i) = e(i) for i=1..n, where e(i) are the base unit vectors in I. This is usually done by using gauss elimination to transform the system to a triangular form, which takes about O(n^3/3) operations. When the triangulation is made it takes O(n^2/2) operations to solve it (backwards substitution). But this has to be done n times, which gives us a total of O(n^4/3) + O(n^3/2) operations, so as you can see we are already over the edge.

However, calculating inv(B) when knowing the cholesky factorization of B is O(n^3) (because solving L*L'*inv(B) = I is the same as solving BE=A)

So we then have: O(n^3/6) (cholesky of B) + O(n^3) (calculating inv(B) with cholesky) + 4*O(2n^3-n^2) (four matrix multiplications) ~ O(9*n^3) which is a little bit better, but still worse.

So I suggest that you stay with your current approach. But you have to keep in mind that this is for large values of n. Unless n is 100+ I don't think it matters that much anyway.